# Do 5 connected pawns usually win against a rook?

Tags: endgame, rook-endgame

Suppose, white has 5 connected pawns, black only a rook. Under normal circumstances
 (black cannot immediately win a pawn, the white pawns are not too far advanced, say
 on the rows 2 to 4, black's king is standing in front of the white pawns)

Can the pawns triumph in such a situation ?

Comment: Not sure about general rule, but here are some examples from real games.
Rook wins: http://chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1506183
Pawns win: http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1506183
Pawns win: http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1619997
Draw: http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1564891

Comment: @GloriaVictis, your "rook wins" link currently points to the same game as your first "pawns win" game. Also, the second "pawns win" game and the drawn game don't feature 5 connected passed pawns; the play involved is still related to that of the question, but worth pointing out that those are different scenarios than the one asked about here.

Comment: @ETD Whoops, missed the "connected" word. Good thing I commented (links only) instead of answering!
The rook wins link is: http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1264266

Comment: The question asked is "can the pawns win?' The answer is definitely yes. If the question had been "will the pawns win?" the answer would definitely be "that depends"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes of course, there are more chances for white who has 5 connected pawns to wins instead of black who has a rook. A rook can't check the king all the time and the pawns are always helping each others to get to the final state to get a queen. This problem is usually won by the 5 pawns.

Comment: This is an opinion (which I happen the believe) but can you support this with analysis?

Comment: T ony, 

I doubt we'll find definitive word - like a mathematical proof, for either side could potentially win under some circumstances (ie not best play).  I know by experience having played in a tournament game with one isolate and four connected, but not so advanced pawns against the rook, the pawns certainly have the advantage.